# How do I render a DateTime object after it has been passed through JSON?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I have a controller that passes a List of objects from a database. Each one has a timestamp of type DateTime. I want to display that in a jQuery DataTable, so I pass the List via JSON to my view. However, each Timestamp is displayed as follows:

```
/Date(1466823108106)/
```

The code that returns the JSON is as follows:

```
return Json(new { draw = draw, recordsFiltered = recordsTotal, recordsTotal = recordsTotal, data = retData }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Any way to keep these parameters and have the Timestamp be readable? Or is that something that should be done on the jQuery Datatables side?

Comment: Oftern easiest to just format the date to a string on the server

Comment: Check this link:http://codeasp.net/blogs/microsoft-net/1306/convert-json-date-to-javascript-date adn demo :http://codeasp.net/assets/demos/blogs/convert-net-datetime-to-javascript-date.aspx